# Best practice calling php class method in script from command line

Tags: php, class, methods, command-line-arguments

I have a basic skeleton php script. I want it to include a class and some methods.

```
   <?php

   class cName{
       public static function  funcName(){
           echo 'this is a test';
       }    
    }

   cName::funcName();
   ?>
```

If I call the file from the command line like this

```
  php fileName.php
```

I get the correct output.

```
  this is a test
```

My question is, with best practice in mind, should I structure the file like this, just calling the file and letting the file call the method. Would it be better to call this method using a command line argument? If so could you explain a little how I might need to change the structure of the file and the format you would suggest for calling file from the command line.

Comment: Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 0):

there is simple ,

```
php /var/www/fileName.php
//    output
> this is a test
```

or you can directly goto to directory of file run

```
www> php fileName.pgp
```

Comment: How is that different to what I'm currently doing?